# javascript filter by key and map the value of the key onto the new object key from another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I construct an object by filtering the keys based on some allowed keys:

```
const configObject = { 
  key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3', key4: 'value4'
};
const allowed = ['key1', 'key3'];

const filtered = Object.keys(configObject)
  .filter(key => allowed.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = configObject[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});

console.log(filtered) // { key1: 'value1', key3: 'value3' }
```

however, i want to get the keys for the new object from a key/value paired object with nice key names:

```
const allowed = [{'key1': 'keyOne'}, {'key3': 'keyThree'}];
```

how can i achieve this to get the following result:

```
 { keyOne: 'value1', keyThree: 'value3' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the entries of the keys object and map the new properties.

```js
var configObject = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3', key4: 'value4' },
    allowed = [{'key1': 'keyOne'}, {'key3': 'keyThree'}],
    filtered = Object.assign(
        ...allowed.map(o => 
            Object.assign(...Object.entries(o).map(([o, n]) =>
                ({ [n]: configObject[o] })))
        )
    );

console.log(filtered);
```

With reduce

```js
var configObject = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3', key4: 'value4' },
    allowed = [{'key1': 'keyOne'}, {'key3': 'keyThree'}],
    filtered = allowed.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([o, n]) => r[n] = configObject[o]);
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: nice one! could you replace the spread syntax with non-spread one? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `allowed` as a dictionary, rather than just a list:

```js
const configObject = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
  key3: 'value3',
  key4: 'value4'
};
const allowed = {'key1': 'keyOne', 'key3': 'keyThree'};
const filtered = Object.keys(configObject)
  .filter(key => Object.keys(allowed).includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[allowed[key]] = configObject[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});

console.log(filtered) // "keyOne": "value1", "keyThree": "value3" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate the `allowed` array, and build the new object from keys that exist on `configObject`:

```js
const configObject = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3', key4: 'value4' };
const allowed = [{'key1': 'keyOne'}, {'key3': 'keyThree'}, 'key2', 'key5']; // I've added key2 as string, and the non existing key5

const result = allowed.reduce((r, o) => {
  // get the key and alias from an object or string
  const [key, alias] = typeof o === 'object' ? Object.entries(o)[0] : [o, o];
  
  if(key in configObject) { // if key exists in configObject
    r[alias] = configObject[key]; // assign it to r;
  }
  
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the allowed array for an object and use the same logic

```js
const configObject = { 
  key1: 'value1', 
  key2: 'value2', 
  key3: 'value3', 
  key4: 'value4'
};

const allowed = {
  key1: 'keyOne',
  key3: 'keyThree'
};
const allowedKeys = Object.keys(allowed)

const filtered = Object.keys(configObject)
  .filter(key => allowedKeys.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[allowed[key]] = configObject[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to get the pretty name from a specific number use a regex:

```
/([a-z]+)(\d+)/i
```

This is for any key like this `keywhatever1111` or `key1` or `anotherkey2`, and so on.

```js
var prettyOnes = {
  '1': 'One',
  '2': 'Two',
  '3': 'Three',
  '11': 'Eleven'
};

const configObject = { 
  key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3', whatever11: 'value11'
};
const allowed = ['key1', 'key3', 'whatever11'];

const filtered = Object.keys(configObject)
  .filter(key => allowed.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    var [_, pre, pretty] = key.match(/([a-z]+)(\d+)/i);
    obj[`${pre}${prettyOnes[pretty]}`] = configObject[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```